# Asp .Net MVC slow - what are detailed steeps between Application_BeginRequest and shared view start processing

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i readed many questions here but all are answered as "set profiling and you got answer"

but i "can not" set profiling to my destination server - or better i need to know what is between Application_BeginRequest and shared view processing

My problem is slow response time from my mvc page
I put in Application_BeginRequest code to write time and i got

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Write("<!" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff") + ">");
           // Response.End();
    }
```

09:19:40.940476
the same i do in my _Layout.cshtml and got

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<! 09:19:44.349476 >
<html lang="pl">
```

As you can see difference is ~3.4 seconds 
Where can i write code to see some times between?
Page is written in MS VS2013 MVC 5
PS. I have debug disabled in web.config of course
 [This slow page can you see at](http://itstop.pl)

On the same server(IIS) i have page [written in Delphi and it work as rocket](http://konwertuj.com)

Comment: You can debug a MVC project on your local machine with step through .net source (load symbols) option set to know what is between Application_BeginRequest and shared view processing?

Comment: Thanks you for hint with load symbols - but this show me "nothing"
But finally i found where the real problem was
I have two version of scripts modernizr-2.6.2.js and modernizr-2.7.1.js and  the same with jquery-ui-1.10.4.js - i remove older and now my page work as expected :)
PS. Can i answer my own question?

Comment: Absolutely. Go ahead and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i found where the real problem was.

I have two version of scripts modernizr-2.6.2.js and modernizr-2.7.1.js 
and the same with jquery-ui-1.10.4.js in scripts folder.
I have removed older and now my page work as expected :)

PS> strange that this affect performance so big